# Rails Form_for Local Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to define a form_for with a local variable, like [section 3.4.4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

I can get it to work using an instance variable, but not with a local one.

**This works:**

Controller.rb

```
@new_instance = @instance_creation.get_instance  #gives a proper object
```

view:

```
= render :partial => '/shared/instances_new'
```

partial view:

```
<%= form_for (@new_instance) do |f| %>
```

**This does not:**

Controller.rb

```
@new_instance = @instance_creation.get_instance  #gives a proper object
```

view:

```
= render :partial => '/shared/instances_new',
                        :new_instance => @new_instance
```

partial view:

```
<%= form_for (new_instance) do |f| %>
```

error:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_instance' for #<#<Class:0x007f8e27dd7b30>:0x007f8e27b0f100>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing object as local

```
= render :partial => '/shared/instances_new', :locals=>{:new_instance => @new_instance}
```

Comment: That's weird, isn't "= render :partial => '/shared/instances_new',                        :new_instance => @new_instance" a shortcut for locals?.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html does not describe such a shortcut, so I assume it isn't.

Comment: @Gaston That shortcut doesn't work when the `:partial` key is supplied.  You need to use the shortcut for the path also: `render 'path/to/partial_view', new_instance: @new_instance`.